# J2ME Detect PTT Request for Motorola Iden

Tags: java, java-me

I have a J2ME application that constantly sends data to server in TCP. During sending, PTT calls cannot be received.

So I wonder if anyone knows how to implement PTT request listener in J2ME so that the J2ME application can terminate the TCP connection to make way for PTT.